# Ex boyfriend remotley erased my phone

Tags: remote-control

Hi wondering if any one would know. Last night my ex boyfriend somehow managed to log onto my account and erase my whole phone   newborn photos of my daughter- all gone. I didnt even know such thing exsisted.
Is there any way of getting the photos back?
Thanks

Comment: It depends. What kind of phone is it? Were the photos only on the phone, or did you have any kind of "auto backup" feature turned on? Were they on the phone's internal storage, or on an SD card. Whatever the answer, your best chance is if you don't use the phone until you can recover them.

Answer (score 0):

Was those picture on your google account? You might have log in to your gmail using his computer and he was able to log back in your account because you're password is automatically remembered and then he access your pictures and deleted them... everything is linked these day, you gotta be careful. Try looking in the trash folder of your google image app

Comment: This is a comment. What facts are you providing? Its also grammatically confusing in the second sentence. And you ended it with a guess.